# Number of solutions of $x^m-y^m=a \pmod p$

Tags: number-theory

I'm interested in the total number of solutions of $x^m-y^m\equiv a \pmod p$ where $p$ is prime.

Is there any way to estimate the total number of solutions ?

I found https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/crll/1935/172/article-p151.xml?language=en is related, but I cannot read German.

Comment: is there any indication to what $a$ is ? It could be anything, right ?

Comment: @Spectre What I gather from the visible part of the linked article is that this is about the usual geometric situation, where $p,m$ and $a$ are given, and the unknowns $(x,y)$ range over $\Bbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen , I am still in the basics and still did the question with what I know... do you think that my answer would be worth staying in here ?

Comment: Oh, Jacobi sums are surely a useful tool here. Don't remember for sure whether Ireland&Rosen or Washington is the appropriate reference. Alas, I don't own either, and don't remember which has an extensive chapter on Jacobi sums and their applications. Probably I&R, but I'm not 100%.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen , you mean that you aren't sure whether my answer is worth standing ?

Comment: I'm not taking a position on that @Spectre. We need the asker to clarify. I didn't check your answer because it seemed to me that you interpreted the question differently than I did, one of the key difference being whether $a$ is a variable or not. Did you check out the linked manuscript in detail? I only looked at the first page.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen , I didn't go through the article at all  () ! But of course, I don't think the OP is so ignorant so as not to be able to calculate remainders...

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. a, p, m are fixed. x and y are the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am interpreting the question to have fixed $p,m,a$ and $x,y$ unknown.

We are obviously only interested in pairwise non-congruent solutions. Or rather, we let $x,y$ range over $\Bbb{Z}_p$, and want to estimate the number of pairs $(x,y)\in\Bbb{Z}_p^2$ satisfying $x^m-y^m=a$. I am replacing congruences modulo $p$ with equations in $\Bbb{Z}_p$ in all that follows. Denote the number of such pairs by $N(m,p,a)$.

Let's first record the standard fact:
$$
N(m,p,a)=N(d,p,a),
$$
where $d=\gcd(m,p-1)$. This follows from the basic properties of cyclic groups. Clearly $x^m=0$ iff $x=0$. The multiplicative group $\Bbb{Z}_p^*$ is known to be a cyclic group of order $p-1$. Therefore the mapping $f:x\mapsto x^m$ is a homomorphism of groups. Its kernel $N$ has size $d$ and its image $M$ thus has size $(p-1)/d$, each element of $M$ the image of a coset of $N$. The exact same thing happens with the mapping $\tilde{f}:x\mapsto x^d$, and the claim follows from this. Ask, if you need something fleshed out (most likely that's done in some other thread on the site already).

The point of that observation was to make $m$ smaller as we can replace it with $d$, and assume that $m\mid p-1$. On with the main business.

The case $a=0$, i.e. the equation $x^m=y^m$, is a special case. With the assumption $m\mid p-1$ in place we can give the exact number of solutions. We have the trivial solution $(x,y)=(0,0)$. If $x$ is non-zero, then $x^m=y^m$ is equivalent to $1=(y/x)^m$
which holds if and only if $y/x\in N$. Therefore to each non-zero choice of $x$ there are exactly $m$ solutions $y$. Hence we can conclude that
$$
N(m,p,0)=1+m(p-1).
$$

On with the main case $a\neq0$, when we bring out the big guns of algebraic geometry.
The equation $x^m=y^m+a$ defines a plane curve. Its projective version, call it $C$, is defined by
the homogenized polynomial equation
$$
F(X,Y,Z):=X^m-Y^m-a Z^m=0.
$$
Here the gradient
$$\nabla F(X,Y,Z)=(mX^{m-1},-mY^{m-1},-amZ^{m-1})$$
vanishes only at $(X,Y,Z)=(0,0,0)$ so $C$ is non-singular. Therefore
the [genus-degree formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus%E2%80%93degree_formula) says that $C$ has genus
$$
g=\frac12(m-1)(m-2).
$$
Next we count the number of points of $C$ on the line at infinity, $Z=0$. We are back in (the projective version of) the case $a=0$, and can conclude that there are exactly $m$ points on the line at infinity, namely $[X:Y:Z]=[1:\zeta:0]$ with $\zeta\in N$ and $m$th root of unity.

It remains to call upon [the results of André Weil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures) giving an upper bound on the difference $\#C(\Bbb{Z}_p)-(p+1)$
of the number of $\Bbb{Z}_p$-rational points of $C$ and $p+1$ (=what we would get if $C$ were a line).

$$|N(m,p,a)+m-(p+1)|\le 2g\sqrt p=(m-1)(m-2)\sqrt p.$$

Basically it says that the number of solutions is $\approx p$, if $m$ is very small in comparison to $p$, and gives an upper bound on the deviation from that expected number otherwise.

Weil's bound becomes in some sense the best possible, if we also consider solutions in the extension field $\Bbb{F}_q, q=p^n$ of $\Bbb{F}_p=\Bbb{Z}_p$. A lot is also known about some special values of $m$. The case $m=3$ being a particularly interesting case as then $g=1$, so we have an elliptic curve.

Comment: Agree @reuns. $m=3$ is the first "interesting" case. IIRC Gauss himself solved that in some sense. I guess there were other interesting special cases settled before Weil's result on curves (and conjectures on higher dimensional varieties), but my knowledge of history is more than a bit shaky here.

Comment: Sorry meant the cases $ m\equiv 0,1,2\mod p-1$ are not too hard. $m\equiv 3$ depends on $a$ ?

Comment: @reuns You wouldn't remember by any chance how this is done with Jacobi sums? Or a good reference? In the course on finite fields and their character sums I took as an undergrad those were ignored, so I don't remember those details as well.

Comment: Yes, when $m\equiv3\pmod {p-1}$ the answer depends on $a$. There is still an unexploited degree of freedom allowing us to conclude that $N(3,p,a)=N(3,p,ab^3)$ for all non-zero $b$. Meaning that the proper domain for $a$ is the multiplicative group modulo cubes.

Comment: The number of $\Bbb{F}_p$-classes of an elliptic curve with a given $j$-invariant are $2,4$ or $6$ depending on if $b$ or $c=0$ in $y^2=x^3+bx+c$ (probably $6$ here). The (linear combination of) Jacobi sums appears from $\sum 1_{ X\in F_p^3}1_{ a-X\in F_p^3}$ where $1_{ X\in F_p^3}$ is a sum of characters. Then a Jacobi sum has an expression in term of Gauss sums.

Comment: $|G(\chi)|=\sqrt{p}$ gives the Weil bound I'd say (this works for every $m$)

Comment: Please flesh that out as an answer @reuns.

Answer (score 2):

***Partial answer: (if $x,y,m,p,a$ are all taken as variables)***

The number of integers in the range $[1, n]$ which can be expressed in the form $a^x−b^y$ is asymptotically $$(\log n)^2 \over {2(\log a)(\log b)}$$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. This is from a result of Pillai. See: [Waldschmidt M., *Perfect Powers: Pillai’s works and their developments*](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Emichel.waldschmidt/articles/pdf/PerfectPowers.pdf)

Also, the equation $p^x − b^y = c$ has been considered by R. Scott in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/sdfe/reader/pii/S0022314X83710413/pdf).

> The equation $p^x − b^y = c$, where $p$ is prime, and $b > 1$ and $c$
> are positive integers, has at most one solution $(x, y)$ when $y$ is
> odd, except for five specific cases, and at most one solution when $y$
> is even.

---

***Answer: (if $a,p$ are given and $x,y.m$ are allowed to vary)***

Let $g$ be a primitive element in the field $GF(p)$. So we have $x = g^r, y = g^s, a = g^t$ for some $r,s,t \in GF(p)$ and $x,y,a$ non-zero elements of $GF(p)$.

$$g^r - g^s \equiv g^t \mod p$$

$$g^{r-t} - g^{s-t} \equiv 1 \mod p$$

$$g^{r-t} \equiv g^{s-t} + 1 \mod p$$

The LHS is non-zero elements in $GF(p)$. The LHS cannot also be $1$ because then $g^{s-t}$ must be 0, which is not possible.

Since every element other than $0$ and $1$ in $GF(p)$ can be represented as a sum of its predecessor + 1 modulo $p$ and the predecessor can also be represented as the power of a primitive element $g$, there are solutions $\forall x,y,a \in GF(p)$ for any given $m$ where the LHS is not $0$ or $1$.

Since there are $p$ values in $GF(p)$ and $0$, $1$ are not representable in the form, we have $p-2$ solutions modulo $p$ for given $a, p, a \ne 0$.

If $a = 0$, we have $p$ trivial solutions $x^m \equiv y^m \mod p$ given by $x \equiv y \mod p$.

Comment: is my answer worth an upvote or acceptance ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming $m$ can be equal to anything and that $m$ can also be equal to $p$.
An easier solution is $a = 0$ when $x = y$ (and I hope you know how we get it).

#### Case 1 : $m = p$

$$\implies x^m \equiv x (\mod{p})$$
and $$y^m \equiv y (\mod{p})$$
(Using Fermat's little theorem)

$\implies x^m - y^m \equiv x - y (\mod{p})$
$\implies x - y = a$

So you have one solution here.

#### Case 2 : $m = np$ for some $n$

$$\implies x^m = (x^n)^p \equiv x^n (\mod{p})$$
and
$$y^m = (y^n)^p \equiv y^n (\mod{p})$$
$\implies x^m - y^m = (x^n)^p - (y^n)^p \equiv x^n - y^n \equiv a(\mod{p})$( Using Fermat's little theorem)

Another solution.

#### Case 3: $m$ and $p$ are relatively prime

If $x, y > p$ :
if $x \equiv u (\mod{p}), x^m \equiv u^m (\mod{p})$
if $y \equiv v (\mod{p}), y^m \equiv v^m (\mod{p})$
Here $a \equiv u^m - v^m (\mod{p})$

And $a$ should vary depending on $u$ and $v$, and for $u > v$, you can have $p$ values for $a$ ($0$ through $p - 1$).

For sure, there should be three solutions, plus some more from the third case.

**Note** : You can have only one solution for $a$ for a constant $u$ and $v$.